# How to apply transform and transition effect on a div

Tags: css

I was practicing css on [an example i found](https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/apxoJX). I tried to show the submenu above the nav with transition effects. I can change the position of the submenu on hover :

```
nav li:hover .menu-sub {
  display: block;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

I also modified the code to add a transition effect:

```
.menu-sub {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: #444;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1.5s ease;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1.5s ease;
    transition: transform 1.5s ease;
}
```

The position changed but I don't see any transition effect at all. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Add your HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify the transition to shown below, it was written wrong.

```
.menu-sub {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: #444;
  width: 100%;
  opacity:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:0px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.5s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease-out;
}
```

Transition does not work with `display`, instead use the below effect.

<kbd>**Codepen Demo**</kbd>


Where we can toggle the `height` from `0px` to `auto`(full height) and `opacity` from `0`(invisible) to `1`(visible). You can see that we only see the animation on `opacity`, this will produce the best effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `visibility:hidden` then `visible`

`display: none` disables it in the active DOM and such elements with this CSS can't be selected for stuffs like animations.

```
.menu-sub {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: #444;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
  transition: transform 1.5s ease;
}
nav li:hover .menu-sub {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```